# accuracer : transaction not working

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7, accuracerdb

Database and the components,query & table are from Accuracer.

I am using a simple delete query :

```
procedure TMain_Form.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
DATA_MODULE.QUERY.Close;
DATA_MODULE.QUERY.SQL.Clear;
//DATA_MODULE.QUERY.SQL.Add('START TRANSACTION;');
DATA_MODULE.QUERY.SQL.Add('delete from TABLE where DONE = TRUE');

try
//DATA_MODULE.QUERY.SQL.Add('COMMIT;');
DATA_MODULE.QUERY.ExecSQL;
DATA_MODULE.TABLE.Refresh;
except
//DATA_MODULE.QUERY.SQL.Text := 'ROLLBACK';
//DATA_MODULE.QUERY.ExecSQL;
DATA_MODULE.TABLE.Cancel;
end;
end;
```

If I leave the query as it is above, it works. As soon as I uncomment the lines, it does not. It just deletes records from my grid but the data in the database is intact.

Am I messing up something here ?

Comment: Is that a in-memory table ? Asking because [`they say`](http://www.accuracer.com/products/acr/guide_bde_alternative_client-server_single-file_embedded_bde_replacement_database_delphi_c++builder_kylix/transactions.php) that *Accuracer supports transactions only for disk databases*.

Comment: no,this is a disk database.

Comment: inMemory property of the query is also set to false...

Comment: I would have asked AidAim support but that is virtually non existent since I have various tickets that are more than a year old with not a comment in them. Documentation sucks and to get some help on the web is almost impossible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems, according to the documentation found here (Multi-User and Multi-Thread, Locking Mechanism and Transactions) : 
http://www.aidaim.com/products/acr/guide_bde_alternative_client-server_single-file_embedded_bde_replacement_database_delphi_c++builder_kylix/index.php

that "- Emptying, Restructuring, Deleting and Renaming tables involved in the transaction " are operations that are incompatible with transactions.

If I am wrong, correct me.

Answer (score 0):

It occurs to me that the statement before COMMIT; has no semicolon. I.e. a simple Syntax Terror